# Convert .HEIC to .JPG with ImageMagick in PHP

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, heic

I am looking to try and create a small image converter that would convert HEIC files that are uploaded to a php web document to .JPG (or any other generic file format).

I am running PHP off a unix server and have ImageMagick installed on the server. The following command line code works from the server:

```
mogrify -format jpg *.HEIC
```

I'd like to convert this command line code to PHP.

As mentioned I like to convert the command line formatting code to PHP. I currently have the following code set up in a basic HTML + PHP form. The file being converted is newly uploaded and not located on the server. If necessary I can upload to the server first then read form the server file.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if(empty($_FILES['image_url']['name']))
    {
        echo "No File uploaded";
    }
    else{

        $uploadedImage = fopen($_FILES['image_url']['tmp_name'], 'rb');

        $image_to_convert = new Imagick();
        $image_to_convert->readImageFile($uploadedImage);
        $image_to_convert->setFormat("jpg");

        $image_to_convert->setFileName('test.jpg');

        header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$image_to_convert->getFileName());
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 

        readfile($image_to_convert);
    }
}
```

This code downloads a "test.jpg" file, but when I try to open it in Windows image viewer it displays a "It looks like we don't support this file format" message. I'm relatively new to PHP so I don't know all the tricks for output/input streams so if my code is horrible let me know.

Any and all help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: You have to have libheif installed in Imagemagick.

Comment: @fmw42 Can you expand on this? I'm not sure I understand how you know it's missing from my library, or why if I don't have it the command line argument works fine server side?

Is my code perfectly fine so the only possible reason it's not working is because I'm missing libheif?

Comment: You could help yourself by 1) saving the incoming file on the server and inspecting it 2) saving the outgoing file on the server before sending it and inspecting it 3) uploading a JPEG instead of HEIF and seeing if that works and 4) using your debugger. You need to narrow it down so you can focus on the actual issue. Good luck!

Comment: The only way I know for sure is if you run `convert -version` and/or `convert -list format` and be sure you see Delegates for HEIC. Normally, Imagemagick installs do not come with HEIC installed. You need to install it with your Imagemagick install. But check those commands on the command line terminal. What is your Imagemagick version and what platform/OS are you running on?

Comment: @fmw42 I am running  ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25 

I checked the convert -list and I see HEIC as an available formatting option.

Again, the conversion works on the command line, I just want to translate that conversion in PHP code so it can convert an uploaded HEIC file to JPG for web clients.

Comment: Try to read an HEIC image and view it without using your forms. Does that work?

Comment: @fmw42 I was able to get it sort of working by first uploading the file to our server, then downloading the uploaded file and doing some clean up. Attempting to download an direct image format didn't work over the web, but I was able to get it working by downloading the HEIC as a PDF.

I was hoping to get it working using only the web browser memory but this works too. Thanks for the suggestions and help!

Comment: If you were trying to read via HTTP or HTTPS, then you may need to edit your Imagemagick policy.xml file to give read permission for HTTP/HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify 'jpeg' rather than 'jpg' for your format.

`$image_to_convert->setFormat("jpeg");`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working after I changed from image formats like png and jpeg, and instead downloaded the converted HEIC image as a .PDF file.

I also had to upload (write) the PDF file to the server first before I was able to download (read) it through the website.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use 3rd party library for conversion [php-heic-to-jpg](https://github.com/MaestroError/php-heic-to-jpg) (linux only).